# pyscripter crashing on startup

Tags: python, ide, pyscripter

I've been using PyScripter for a few months now with no issue, but when I tried to open the application today it's just been crashing with the error message

> "PyScripter has stopped working: A problem caused the program to stop
>   working correctly. Please close the program."

I'm unsure what is causing the error and so far I've been unable to fix it.

I don't believe I did anything the last time I used PyScripter which might have caused it to break.

Comment: Make sure everything is up to date. It might also be an anti virus software stopping the program, check if it works with your anti virus disabled and afterwards if you can add it to exceptions/trusted programs so on.

Comment: My software is up to date and I tried running the program with the firewall down and it didn't seem to fix the issue